# Can I shutdown my computer automatically when it's far away from some location?

Tags: windows-7, geolocation, anti-theft

Can I automatically shutdown my laptop when, for example, it is 5km away from my home, and then also prevent it from being switched on again?

The computer won't be connected to the internet.

Comment: You can precise why you want to do this and which OS do you have on your laptop. Also, is your computer connected to Internet?

Comment: i am using windows 7 and computer not connected to internet

Comment: Is internet access not available period?  Is telephone?  I'm imagining a hack involving a raspberry pi listening for a code on a phone line or something similar.  At 5k distances, you're talking about wireless signals that are regulated by the FCC (in the united states, similar regulatory bodies exist elsewhere), which might cause you some headache.

Comment: Hi, is the purpose of your question is to have a protective system that would put the system in a lock down when you suspect it is stolen (like suggested by Hennes' answer)?

Comment: yes!that is what i meant

Answer (score 2):

> Can I automatically shutdown my laptop when, for example, it is 5km
>   away from my home,

I have seen solutions where you carry a bluetooth device (dedicated hardware or as an app on a phone). When that connection fails (read: when you walk away from your computer and exceed the range) then the computer would lock.

Technically there is no reason why you could not change that to a shutdown.

Bluetooth is limited to max 100 meters though, not 5km.

For that a GPS receiver would be needed, and some software. Which you might have to write yourself.

> and then also prevent it from being switched on again?

This would not stop people from turning the computer back on, but they would need to know the BIOS/EFI password to get to your data. Combine that with full disk encryption and the laptop would be useless.

Comment: Indeed, solutions that require *some other device* to be in the neighbourhood are probably easier than trying to determine the location of the computer; while mobile phones often have GPS, laptops still often do not have that.

Comment: ...though, just for the sake of completeness: lacking GPS, computers might use the locations of known WiFi access points (if any) to roughly determine where they are. (But unlike most mobile phones, a computer will then often not have internet access, so cannot tell some service about their whereabouts. "Find my Mac/PC" is really not that useful as "Find my Phone".)

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can shutdown a computer from a remote location using mobile phone apps or via pre-installed dropbox in mobile phone, You just need to do some editing in scripts.

Comment: Any more details? To me, this just reads as "Yes". Also, how would the computer connect to the internet to be controlled remotely?

Comment: Welcome to SU!  This answer needs more details to be useful.  Please provide an explanation or a tutorial (or link to one) for the techniques you describe.